# GDB skips padding when loading ELF to target

Tags: gdb, elf, armv7, openocd

I have a STM32F4 Discovery board, OpenOCD debug server and armv7m-unknown-eabi-gdb and want my board to run a bare-metal ELF which I've built. I start gdb, give it `target remote :3333`, `load`, `monitor reset halt` commands and then try to step through the code but nothing works. After some investigation I've found that the code was uploaded at a wrong address.

readelf -S gives:

```
[ 1] vectors           PROGBITS        00000000 000114 000040 00   A  0   0  1
[ 2] .interp           PROGBITS        00000040 000154 000011 00   A  0   0  1
[ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM          00000054 000168 000030 10   A  4   3  4
[ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB          00000084 000198 000001 00   A  0   0  1
[ 5] .hash             HASH            00000088 00019c 000018 04   A  3   0  4
[ 6] .text             PROGBITS        000000a0 0001b4 000134 00 WAX  0   0  4
```

And you can see that the linker put two 3-byte paddings: the first one between .interp and .dynsym and the second one between .dynstr and .hash sections.

But when gdb loads the image onto the board it seems to ignore these gaps and put the sections one right after the other (nevermind 0x2xxxxxxx addresses, the CPU is configured to map them to 0x0xxxxxxx region):

```
(gdb) load
Loading section vectors, size 0x40 lma 0x20000000
Loading section .interp, size 0x11 lma 0x20000040
Loading section .dynsym, size 0x30 lma 0x20000051
Loading section .dynstr, size 0x1 lma 0x20000081
Loading section .hash, size 0x18 lma 0x20000082
Loading section .text, size 0x134 lma 0x2000009a
```

As the result the code finds itself 6 bytes before the address GDB expects it to be at and thus all the debugging info applies to memory incorrectly. I literally get crazy results because the next instruction I'm going to execute (that is the one which GDB points at) in fact is some other one (to be exact, it's the current instruction + 3 halfwords).

So, what can be wrong? Do I use GDB incorrectly? Or is it ELF that was build wrongly? Maybe OpenOCD is the culprit? Or something else?

**Edit**

It looks like GDB does its job according to what is written in the ELF. LMA addresses of .dynsym and .hash sections are really not aligned.

objdump -h gives:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 vectors       00000040  00000000  20000000  00000114  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .interp       00000011  00000040  20000040  00000154  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .dynsym       00000030  00000054  20000051  00000168  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .dynstr       00000001  00000084  20000081  00000198  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .hash         00000018  00000088  20000082  0000019c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .text         00000134  000000a0  2000009a  000001b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, CODE
```

It also turns out that .interp, .dynsym, .dynstr, and .hash sections were generated by the linker because GCC gave it -pic flag. I didn't mention these sections in my linker script. So I need to understand why ld aligned VMA addresses but didn't LMA ones.